# Trying to Create nested dropdown, child popup appears when parent is hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I need help figuring out how to show a dropdown. Then click a button in the dropdown and get a new "child" dropdown/popup and clear out the previous "parent" dropdown.

The problem I have right now is that my parent and child popup appear at the same time when i click on the parent popup link. I want the parent and child to be open and closed at separate times not at the same time.

HTML for the child and parent dropdowns:

```html
<div class="dropdown conversation-dropdown" style="float:left;margin-top:5px;">
<%= link_to "#", class:'btn btn-noti dropdown-toggle', role:'button', 'aria-expanded' =>'false', data:{toggle: 'dropdown'} do %>

 <span class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:25px;"></span>


<% end %>

 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:500px;margin-left:-440px;">
  <li class="dropdown-header">
  <div class="row">

  <div style="float:left;">
  <h class="" >Conversations</h>
  </div>

<!-- child popup -->

<div class="dropdown new-message-dropdown" style="float:right;">

<%= link_to "", class:'btn dropdown-header', role:'button', 'aria-expanded' =>'false', data:{toggle: 'dropdown'} do %>
 <h style="margin-right:10px;">New Message</h>
<% end %>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:500px;margin-left:-440px;">
  <li class="dropdown-header">New Message</li>
  </ul>


</div>


<!-- end child popup -->


  </div>
  </li>

  <%= render current_user.conversations.order('created_at DESC').last(8) %>
    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
        <li ">
          <%= render 'conversations/conversation_dropdown' %>
        </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot embed rails helper and make it work in stack overflow code snippet. Can you make a working copy of the same to show the problem ?

Comment: Please post some relevant code and if possible please create a fiddle

Comment: If my answer helped can you mark the answer

Answer (score 1):

Is this the kind of thing you are looking for:
[Expand/Collapse pure CSS/HTML](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-expand-collapse)

I accidentally stumbled across it late last night.

Hope it helps